# How to detect the mySQL version using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I can use:

```
extension_loaded('mysql')
```

to check if mySQL is installed on the server or not.

also phpinfo() can display a nice phpinfo page.

but how to get which mysql version is installed on server? is there any function like:

```
which_extension_version('mysql') //output the mysql version?
```

just like the **PHP_VERSION**?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`mysql_get_server_info()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php) after connect with mysql_connect

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with:

```
mysqli_get_server_version();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
[mysql_get_server_info()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php)